# cygwin binary exec format error

Tags: linux, windows, bash, cygwin

I have a script file that I was given to run in windows using Cygwin. When I try to use this file I get the following error

> -bash: /sigdet/filename: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.

sigdet is the folder within the Cygwin directory that I have the script. Rawdata is the name of the directory with the raw data files that the script is supposed to analyze.

To try and solve this, I have changed the file permissions, I have checked to make sure that it is on a 64 bit machine and the script appears to have compiled on a 64-bit machine. After these steps, I don't know what else the problem could be. Here are the commands I've entered:

I first changed the directory like so:

> $ cd /sigdet/

Then I ran the script that is suppsed to work:

> $ /sigdet/filename -i rawdata

Does the script file need to have an extension in windows? I've tried changing it to a .sh extension with no luck. I'm told that it just works on other windows machines just how it is.

Thanks to anyone that can help with this.

Comment: The file is protected by copywrite so I can't upload that information, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your file is not an executable. **It most probably contains ELF executable which is designed for Linux operating system, or it's corrupt.**
2. If your file was a shell script, or in fact anything that contained plain text, you'd get different errors (such as, "expected command name" or "unknown command: XYZ" etc.)
3. Scripts are not supposed to have file extensions, like any executables. On the other hand, they should have shebangs: small text located in the first line that tells the system the path to the interpreter. For example, a Python executable script might be named `whatever` and have `#!/usr/bin/python3` or similar in the first line. When you run it through `./whatever` in the shell, it'll look for `python3` in `/usr/bin` and run your file like this: `/usr/bin/python3 ./whatever`. (In fact, thanks to this you can also specify additional parameters that get passed to the interpreter.)

There is also a chance that your script is valid, but it contains a shebang pointing to bad interpreter. If that is the case, then most likely the path is correct, otherwise you'd get `/whatever/interpreter: bad interpreter: no such file or directory` error or similar. But then, all the other points apply to the interpreter (which is just another executable...)

If the script and/or interpreter was meant to be executed on Windows or Cygwin at least, it should either contain aforementioned shebang (`#!/path` in the first name) or it should be Windows executable (in which case the file data should begin with `MZ` letters, you can inspect it in notepad.) If it isn't, it means the files you were given can't run on Cygwin.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, rr-. I opened the file in notepad and it has ELF at the beginning. Does this mean that I cannot run the script unless I am using Linux?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the case.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem. Added the following at the top of makefile:

export ARCH = CYGNUS

What happened during the make process is that Linux and Windows versions of the executables were created. You just have to use ./.exe versions.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got the error when I used a wrong command to compile my C program. When I used the right command:

```
gcc myprog.c -o myprog.exe
```

the error was resolved.